# How can I disable redelivery of tasks in celery (with redis)?

Tags: python, redis, celery

Is there for me to configure celery to just drop the tasks in case of a non-graceful shutdown of a worker? Its more critical for me that tasks are not repeated rather than they are always delivered.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#id1):

> If a task isn’t acknowledged within the Visibility Timeout the task will be redelivered to another worker and executed.
>
> This causes problems with ETA/countdown/retry tasks where the time to execute exceeds the visibility timeout; in fact if that happens it will be executed again, and again in a loop.
>
> So you have to increase the visibility timeout to match the time of the longest ETA you’re planning to use.

My use case is that I am using a `visibility_timeout` of 1 day, but still in some cases that is not enough- I want to schedule tasks even further in the future. "Power failure" or any other event causing a non-graceful shutdown is very rare and I'm fine with tasks being dropped in, say, 0.01% of the cases. Moreover, a task executed 1 day later than it was supposed to, is as bad as the task not being run at all.

One obvious, hacky, way is to set `visibility_timeout` to 100 years. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `acks_late` configuration, but the default value is `false` (so make sure you didn't enable it):

> The acks_late setting would be used when you need the task to be
> executed again if the worker (for some reason) crashes mid-execution.
> It’s important to note that the worker isn’t known to crash, and if it
> does it’s usually an unrecoverable error that requires human
> intervention (bug in the worker, or task code).

(quote from [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.0.1/faq.html#should-i-use-retry-or-acks-late))

The definition of `task_acks_late` (seems like the name has changed in the last version of some mismatch) can be found [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.0.1/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-late).

Comment: Good thing is that acks_late can be set per-task as well as globally.